# HighStocks - How to create custom RangeSelectors buttons and Input date

Tags: highcharts

How to create custom RangeSelectors buttons and Input date, having the same behavior as like In built RangeSelectors buttons and input date/

Example : more that three line graph chart data , of which one will be benchmark line data

Any working code example will be of great help.

below is the sample screen shot.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to use the built-in buttons and change their layour/behaviour or do you want to create buttons in html which are completely separated from the chart but are able to affect it?

Comment: @morganfree, yes i want the html which are completely separated from the chart but are able to affect it

Comment: Basically, range selector only sets extremes and data grouping.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Axis.setDataGrouping Using these two methods you are able to achieve what range selector does. http://jsfiddle.net/8e63b3qp/

Comment: @morganfree Thank you for your answer.